# After performing dropDuplicates() am getting different counts when taking the count

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I did dropDuplicates in a dataframe with subsets of `Region,store`,and `id`.

The dataframe contains some other columns like `latitude, longitude, address, Zip, Year, Month`...

When I do count of the derived dataframe am getting a constant value,
But when i take the count of a selected year, say 2018, am getting different counts when running the `df.count()`

Could anyone please explain why this is happening?

```
Df.dropDuplicates("region","store","id")

Df.createOrReplaceTempView(Df)
spark.sql("select * from Df").count() is constant
```

whenever i run

But if i put a where clause inside with Year or Month am getting multiple counts.

Eg:

```
spark.sql("select * from Df where Year =2018").count()
```

This statement is giving multiple values on each execution.
Intermediate output
Region  store  objectnr  latitude  longitude  newid  month  year      uid
Abc       20       4572       46.6383   8.7383       1          4           2018     0
Sgs        21      1425       47.783      6.7282       2          5        2019       1
Efg        26       1277       48.8293    8.2727      3          7        2019      2

Output

Region  store  objectnr  latitude  longitude  newid  month  year      uid
Abc       20       4572       46.6383   8.7383       1277        4           2018     0
Sgs        21      1425       47.783      6.7282       1425        5        2019       1
Efg        26       1277       48.8293    8.2727      1277       7        2019      2

So here newid gets the value of objecrnr,
When newid is comming same then i need to assign the latest objectnr to newid, considering the year and month

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Df.dropDuplicates("region","store","id")
```

creates a new Dataframe and it is not modifying the existing one. Dataframes are immutable.

To solve your issue you need to save the output of the dropDuplicates statement into a new Dataframe as shown below:

```scala
val Df2 = Df.dropDuplicates("region","store","id") 
Df2.createOrReplaceTempView(Df2) 
spark.sql("select * from Df2").count()
```

In addition you may get different counts when applying the filter Year=2018 because the Year column ist not part of the three columns you used to drop the duplicates. Apparently you have date in your Dataframe that share the same values in the three column but differ in the Year. Dropping duplicates is not a deterministic process ass it depends on the ordering of your data which vary in every run on your code.

Comment: So how can i remove those extra rows of year, any suggestions?

Comment: Well, this should be done based on business requirements how to deal with rows that share the same region store and id but with a different year and not from a technical perspective. So what is the business requirement or your use case?

Comment: This is not sufficient information to deal with your problem. You need to be much more precise and ideally have a minimal reproducable example in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe your problem there, not in the comments. Also, it might be beneficial to show an example of input and expected output data.